# cannot authenticate with postgres

Tags: postgresql, docker

I'm trying to connect and run postgres container with psql:

```
docker pull postgres

docker run -e  POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password -d postgres

C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\bin>psql <myUserName>
Password for user <myUserName>:
```

at this point when I type the password, it shows the error

```
psql: error: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "<myUserName>"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In my hands, your 2nd command never gives back a command prompt.  So where is your 3rd command getting executed from?

Comment: You don't create a database user named "<myUserName>".  The password you told it to use got assigned to user named "postgres".

Comment: Do you have running postgresql service on your machine ?

Comment: @Amin yes, this command "docker run -e  POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password -d postgres" just starts it. We can confirm it by running "docker ps", which returns: "c792cdeae2d4   postgres  "docker-entrypoint.s…"   14 seconds ago   Up 13 seconds   5432/tcp  boring_satoshi"

Answer (score 1):

When you use `docker run -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password -d postgres`, the `POSTGRES_PASSWORD` would be set for user `postgres` as default. you can specify your user with `POSTGRES_USER` environment.

Second thing is that when you run a postgresql container and don't bind any ports for that, you can't connect to that container from outside. So you won't being able to connect to your container with pure `pqsl` command. Here you have 3 way to connect to your container:

1- Use `docker run -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password -p 5432:5432 -d postgres` to run container, then connect to it with `psql -h <YOUR_IP> -p 5432 -U <USERNAME>`

2- Get your container ip with `docker inspect <CONTAINER_NAME>` command, then connect to it with `psql -h <CONTAINER_IP> -U <USERNAME>`

3- Use `psql` inside your container with `docker exec -it <CONTAINER_NAME> psql -U <USERNAME>`

Comment: It does not help, I'm still getting this error message: "psql: error: could not connect to server: Connection timed out (0x0000274C/10060)
        Is the server running on host "172.17.0.2" and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?"

Comment: Which option did you take ? @Jaana